# Node.js Socket.io Heroku "no method 'Configure'"

Tags: node.js, heroku, socket.io

I'm trying to get socket.io set up on Heroku, so I have this code on my main script:

```
var io = require('socket.io');

io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
```

When I try to run, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Object #(Object) has no method 'configure'
```

I have Socket.io in the dependencies, and I've tried adding a .listen() but then I get a "has no method 'listeners' error.

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.configure(function () { 
  io.set("transports", ["xhr-polling"]); 
  io.set("polling duration", 10);
});
```

You trying to configure wrong object. Method listen creates Socket.IO instance.